# Hotel Search System

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, search

I need to build a hotel search spring boot application.

The issue that I was confused about is the hotel system objects must be build up in an object-oriented manner.

So I build up some objects, but the question is how will I search this in the JPA repository.

Mainly JPA works with one or two tables,

but in this case, I need to use all of the tables to return the result.

Do you recommend writing custom SQL for that?

And the second issue, how will I search for availability. I decided to keep the availability matrix per room because hotels can have several rooms.

Querying hotels, cities, etc. are easy but the date range in multiple rooms that a hotel keeps is the challenge?

How could I put this in my query in this case?

Thanks,
Regards.

City

```
package com.booking.hotel.entity;

import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class City {

    private long id;

    private String name;

    List<Hotel> hotelList;

}
```

Hotel.java

```
package com.booking.hotel.entity;

import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Hotel {

    private String name;

    private City city;

    private int ranking;

    private String location;

    private int distanceToCenter;

    private List<Room> roomList;

}
```

Room.java

```
package com.booking.hotel.entity;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Room {

    private long id;

    private long hotelId;

    private String type;

    private BigDecimal pricePerNight;

    private int roomSize;

    private boolean wiFi;

    private boolean airCondition;

    HashMap<Date, Boolean> availabilityHashMap;

    private Room() {
        // initialize room available by default
    }

}
```

Comment: you need the relate the models with each other to get results that you want, try to look entity relationships in jpa topic, after that you can createt query methods to bring desired data from db

Comment: How did you solve the problem?